# Paste a number as macro

Tags: r, macros

Consider the following dataset:

```
d <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(d) <- c("2000","2001")
```

I want to make the following subset:

```
d2 <- data.frame(d$`2000`)
```

However, instead of using `$2000`, I want to create a macro which I can use instead. For instance,

```
year <- 2000
```

How do I use this new value as a macro. I have tried with:

```
d2 <- data.frame(d$`formula(paste(year))`)
```

But this does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `d[as.character(year)]`

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the `year` value to character and then select the column.

```
d[as.character(year)]

#   2000
#1     1
#2     1
#3     1
#4     0
#5     1
#6     0
#7     1
#8     1
#9     1
#10    0
```

Or similarly with `dplyr::select`

```
dplyr::select(d, as.character(year))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` and `colnames` to *select the column*.

```
d[match(year, colnames(d))]
#   2000
#1     1
#2     1
#3     1
#4     1
#5     0
#6     0
#7     0
#8     0
#9     1
#10    0
```

or `which`.

```
d[which(year == colnames(d))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usign `dplyr` you can do:

```
d %>% select(paste0(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toString` or `class` (similar to the solution `as.character()` by [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59370004/12158757)), i.e.,

```
d2 <- d[toString(year)]
```

or

```
d2 <- d[`class<-`(year,"character")]
```

Both of them will get

```
> d2
   2000
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
```